# Where to put this line of code for custom button font?

Tags: java, android, xml, button, fonts

Where should I put this code

```
 Button txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "customfont.ttf");  
    txt.setTypeface(font);
```

so I can change the font of the text that is displayed on my button?
I just want the font on the button changed. I am not trying to change the font in the alert dialog box. I just don't know where to put the code to change the button font.  I already have the custom font placed inside a "fonts" folder located in assets.

Here is the xml part of the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="alertBtn"
    android:text="Click for message" 
    android:textSize="22sp"
    />
```

Here is the code of my project:

```
package com.test.hellothere;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HelloThereActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    }

    public void onClick(View v){}

    public void alertBtn(View v){

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Hello")
        .setMessage("Hello There!")
        .setNeutralButton("Go Back", null)
        .show();
    }

    }
```

Comment: after `setContentView();`

Comment: if the font is under a subfolder, it should be referred to in the path, i.e. `Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/customfont.ttf")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your code inside `onCreate` of Activity after `setContentView` as:

```
public class HelloThereActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 Button txt;
 Typeface font;
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  

       // call here for setting font 
       setfonttoView(txt);

       //.....same for other buttons
    }
  public void setfonttoView(Button button){
       font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "customfont.ttf");  
       button.setTypeface(font);
    }

  //your code here...
```

Comment: Thanks, also is there a way to set the font for multiple buttons at once so I dont have to keep retyping the code over and over, and also for neatness purposes?

Comment: @CaptnBuzz : just create an method in same class and pass button instance to it as parameter for setting font to multiple buttons

Comment: can you show me an example? sorry for all the questions

Comment: sweet thanks you just taught me a lot more haha :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Button txt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "customfont.ttf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

within `onCreate()`